# I need to pass some data through some components React

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a broker simulator and I need to pass the data (side,price,volume,timestamp) into different tab, which is like grandparent's brother. The problem is I have no idea, how to transport data that far

Modalbuy.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./modal.css";

const Modalbuy = ({active, setActive,price}) => {





    return (
        <div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"} onClick={() => setActive(false)}>
          <div className="modal__content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <header>Make order</header>
            <p>BUY {price}</p>
            <input placeholder="Volume">{volume}</input>
            <div>
              <button onClick={() =>{this.props.addData("BUY", price, volume,)}}>Ok</button>
              <button>Cancel</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modalbuy;
```

Select.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './select.css'
import Modalbuy from "../popup/Modalbuy"
import Modalsell from "../popup/Modalsell"
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Select = () => {

    
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const [usdrub, setUsdrub] = useState(Math.random() * (64-61) + 61);
    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setUsdrub(Math.random() * (64-61) + 61);
      }, 10000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])

    const [rubusd, setRubusd] = useState(Math.random() * 2);
    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setRubusd(Math.random() * 2);
      }, 10000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])



    function changeSelect(event) {
        setValue(event.target.value)
    }
    const [modalBuyActive, setModalBuyActive] = useState(false)
    const [modalSellActive, setModalSellActive] = useState(false)

    function addData(side, price, volume, timestamp) {
        this.setState({side:side, price:price, volume:volume, timestamp:timestamp})
    }



    return (
        <div>
        <select value = {value} onChange={changeSelect}>
         <option>Choose instrument</option>   
        <option name="USD/RUB" value={usdrub}>USD/RUB</option>
        <option name="RUB/USD" value={rubusd}>RUB/USD</option>
        </select>
        <div className="Curr">
          <div className="Buy" name="buy"> <button className="Buy" type="btn" onClick={() => setModalBuyActive(true)}>BUY {value + 1} </button>
          </div>
          <div className="Sell" name="sell"><button className="Sell" type="btn"  onClick={() => setModalSellActive(true)}>SELL {value}</button></div>
          </div>
          <Modalbuy active={modalBuyActive} setActive={setModalBuyActive} price={value + 1} addData={addData}/>
          <Modalsell active={modalSellActive} setActive={setModalSellActive} price={value}/>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Select
```

Trading.js

```
import React from "react";
import Timer from "./Timer";
import Select from "./select_curr/Select";

const Trading = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        <Timer/>
        <Select/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Trading;
```

Page.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tabs, TabList, TabPanel, Tab } from 'react-re-super-tabs'
import CustomTab from './customTab'
import Trading from '../trading/Trading.js'
import Table from '../archive/table'

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <Tabs activeTab='about'>
      <TabList>
        <Tab component={CustomTab} label='Trading' id='trading' />
        <Tab component={CustomTab} label='Archive' id='archive' />
      </TabList>
      <TabList>
        <TabPanel component={Trading} id='trading' />
        <TabPanel component={Table} id='table' />

      </TabList>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Page;
```

So I need to make a table in Table.js and import there data I got from module dialogue

Comment: Simply move your data/state to higher component in your example to `Page.js`.
I recommend to use context to omit the props drilling
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the way I understand your problem, The component `Modalbuy` need to share data with your component `Table`.
Here are some way I can advise you.

#### 1. The common Parent manage the state

```
const Page = () => {
  const [yourData, setYourData] = useState([])
  return (
    [...]
    <TabPanel component={props=>(<Trading {...props} value={yourData} onChange={setYourData} />)} id='trading' />
    <TabPanel component={props=>(<Table {...props} value={yourData} onChange={setYourData} />)} id='table' />
    [...]
  )
}
```

This implies intermediate component are in charge to follow those new props to `Modalbuy`

#### 2. Using Redux librairy

Redux is basicly a librairy to help you to define a global state for your app. You define actions your components can call to transform this global state. On the other way, components can subscribe to that state to be refreshed when a change happen.
Don't hesitate to have a look to tutorials https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

#### 3. Using React Context

```
export const YourDataContext = React.createContext({})
const Page = () => {
  const [yourData, setYourData] = useState([])
  return (
    <YourDataContext.Provider value={{yourData, setYourData}}>
    [...]
    </YourDataContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
const Modalbuy = ({active, setActive,price}) => {
  const { yourData, setYourData } = React.useContext(YourDataContext)
  [...]
})
```

You define a context `YourDataContext`. You share a value to this context, here we create a state and passing the getter/setter. All child of the Provider can access the attribute `value` with the hook React.useContext(YourDataContext)

Comment: Using a context, should I use Form fragment to add data to yourData? Or I just pass the arguments into setYourData in Modalbuy in button onClick?

Comment: Also, after adding a context, my tabs just disappeare

Comment: `setYourData` is a setState. If you want to manage a list, just build an item with the data you collect and insert it into the array `setYourData([...yourData, {action:"BUY", price, volume}])`